# How to verify that the set: $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x=3y \ \text{and} \ z=-y$ is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to verify that the set $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x=3y \ \text{and} \ z=-y\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, I am not sure how to do this. Normally questions of this flavor have only one equation. With two, how can I verify closure under addition? Do I do it for two equations separately or do I need to somehow combine them? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show that the intersection of two subspaces is always a subspace itself? If so, then you can just check each individual subspace, and you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$(x,y,z)=(3y,y,-y)=y(3,1,-1)\cong\mathbb{R}$$
As it is isomorphic to a subspace itself must also be a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:x=3y, z=-y\}$ we see that $v\in S$ is in the form $v=a(3,1,-1)$ for $a\in\Bbb R$. Clearly $0\in S$ so now we check that $S$ is closed under real multiplication and addition. Let $v,w\in S$ such that $v=(3x,x,-x)$ and $w=(3y,y,-y)$ for $x,y\in\Bbb R$, and let $a,b\in\Bbb R$.
$$av+bw\\=a(3x,x,-x)+b(3y,y,-y)\\=(3(ax+by),(ax+by),-(ax+by))\\=(ax+by)(3,1,-1)$$
Thus $av+bw\in S$ so $S$ is a subspace.